# How to stop page reloading in flutter after using setState in Checkbox

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I use flutter web I put a checkbox for users. The problem is that the page contains a different TextField.So, in the event that the user selects one of the Checkbox options, a page refresh occurs.Then all TextField data is reloaded and all data that was previously inserted is deleted.The problem is caused by setState(()).But I can't delete it if the setState checkbox is deleted. The checkbox doesn't work.

```
  bool _checkbox = false;

 Checkbox(
    value: _checkbox,
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        _checkbox = !_checkbox;

      });
    },
  );
```

How can this problem be solved without deleting the data from the fields?

Thank you

Comment: Create a `text editing controller` for each `TextField` and attach to each `TextField`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrap in `StatefulBuilder` to reload only the checkbox